# Prestashop Import multiple images for combinations via CSV import

Tags: import, prestashop

In PrestaShop 1.5.4 while importing combinations by default we can't import multiple images via CSV. It only takes one image and if we add more than one image links in the csv import file and upload it then all product images shows as blank. I've already tried the image position and that seems to be working the same way as we can define only one image position.

Is there any way or anyone used any other method may be editing code by which they have been succeeded importing multiple images ? Please do share with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Images;
http://www.domin.com/image/abc.png,http://www.domin.com/image/xyz.png

Use comma for multiple file seperation, Like wise upload the files and select the attribute value as Image URLs...
It it is the last column don't use ";" it not use ";" .

Comment: Have you tried yourself ? In prestashop version 1.5 this was not working. I have not tested din PS 1.6.